Sahlqvist correspondence of the formula $\Diamond \Box \varphi \to \Diamond \Box \Box \varphi$
If my understanding is correct, the modal formula  $\Diamond \Box \varphi \to \Diamond \Box \Box \varphi$ is a Sahlqvist formula.
Therefore, there is a corresponding first-order sentence that holds in a Kripke frame iff $\Diamond \Box \varphi \to \Diamond \Box \Box \varphi$ is valid in that frame.
I am having trouble applying the Sahlqvist algorithm (see e.g. Theorem 19 in the textbook Modal Logic for Open Minds by van Benthem) to figure what is the corresponding first-order condition. My intuition (for what its worth) is that the modal formula corresponds to the condition: in any world, there is an accessible world in which the $R$ relation is transitive.
Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

By coincidence this week I had to compute the Sahlqvist correspondent of this formula. Your intuition is not far off. The first-order formula I got, after some rearrangement, was the following:
$$\forall x,y(xRy \rightarrow \exists k(xRk \wedge \forall w,m(kRw \wedge wRm \rightarrow yRm)).$$
I hope this gives you some help in figuring out how you are operating the algorithm; let me know if you'd like some additional insight into how I computed the above!

The software system SQEMA computes Sahlqvist correspondents such as the one you are looking for, and also provides a proof.
